# peekService returns null even though startService does not

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to use an Android `Service` from a `BroadcastReceiver`. The `Service` lives in a different application than the `BroadcastReceiver`. My understanding is that the right way to do this is to first call `Context#startService`, followed by `BroadcastReceiver#peekService`. The call to `startService` seems to work correctly, as it returns the expected `ComponentName`. However, when I make the call to `peekService`, `null` is returned. Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you! Here is a code listing with the relevant parts.

```
// The Service in question is com.tingley.myapp.MyService
// Note that this Receiver is in a different application
package com.tingley.myotherapp;

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    // Start the Service
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent();
    serviceIntent.setClassName("com.tingley.myapp", "com.tingley.myapp.MyService");
    ComponentName componentNameOfStartedService = context.startService(serviceIntent);
    Log.d("", "Started service name: " + componentNameOfStartedService);

    // Get an IBinder to the Service
    IBinder serviceBinder = peekService(context, serviceIntent);
    Log.d("", "Got binder from peeking service: " + serviceBinder);
  }
}
```

The `Log` statements print the following:

```
Started service name: ComponentInfo{com.tingley.myapp/com.tingley.myapp.MyService}
Got binder from peeking service: null
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for [peekService()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#peekService(android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent)) does not fully describe the conditions required to get an IBinder.  As Dianne Hackborn (Google Android engineer) explains in [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/yiq_XIzFoS4): "Calling `startService()` is not enough -- you need to have called `bindService()` for the same intent, so the system had retrieved the `IBinder` for it".